# UITesting Swift for a segmented Control

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel, uisegmentedcontrol, xcode-ui-testing

I have a label indicating the selected segment text .

By default the label.text = "Timetable"

On loading the segment i will update this label text with selected segment text.

In my UITestCase, i have the following code:-

```
func testTargetMotionSettings() {
    let app = XCUIApplication() // root of tree of UI elements
//        app.segmentedControls.buttons["Settings"].tap()

    let outputLabel = app.staticTexts.matching(identifier: "Stimulus motion type").element

//        app.buttons["Departures"].tap()
    XCTAssertEqual((outputLabel.value as! String), "Departures")

    app.buttons["Arrivals"].tap()
    XCTAssertEqual((outputLabel.value as! String), "Arrivals")

}
```

So "Stimulus motion type" is the identifier given to the label
[image]

But it fails with "XCTAssertEqual failed: ("") is not equal to ("Departures") - "

Please help

Answer (score 2):

As long as you haven't specified a custom accessibility label, UILabel automatically falls back to its text value for the accessibility label. This means you can access the text of the label using `XCUIElement.label` rather than `XCUIElement.value`:

```
func testTargetMotionSettings() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let outputLabel = app.staticTexts["Stimulus motion type"]

    app.buttons["Departures"].tap()
    XCTAssertEqual(outputLabel.label, "Departures")

    app.buttons["Arrivals"].tap()
    XCTAssertEqual(outputLabel.label, "Arrivals")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not access the text of the element in this way. the outputlabel is an XCUIElement object and the value of it is not the text of the label ! 
So basically you don't have access to your UILabel.

I suggest you to use some frameworks like [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF) which will be in UnitTest Target and you can access your classes and everything in your project. but in UITest target and just working with XCUITest elements is so limited.

For example with KIF you can find your segmentController object by :

```
let segmentController = tester().waitForView(withAccessibilityLabel: "SegmentViewAccessabilityLabel") as? SegmentedControllerView
```